# How to open .org files with emacs in ranger?

Tags: unix, emacs, org-mode

So in my rifle.conf I have

```
ext org, has emacs,    terminal,  flag f = emacs "$@"
```

However it opens the file with the GUI version of emacs?
How do I open it with 'emacs -nw filename'?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Interesting dig - after a look at OPs solution above: It turns out ranger does indeed open a terminal program 'on top of itself', so to speak.
The culprit in OPs first attempt is the `flag f`, in fact the minimal

```
ext org = emacs -nw "$@"
```

works like a charm.

**Old attempts:**

As far as I read the docs, you cannot open a file with a program running in the same terminal as ranger itself is running
in (I may be wrong, though).

Following the documentation I exported `TERMCMD`, since I'm using tmux with `TERM=screen-256color`, `ranger` cannot infer the terminal to use from that:

```
# just a test, I don't use xterm
export TERMCMD=xterm
```

And simply added the `t` flag and `-nw` to the command in `rifle.conf`:

```
 ❯ cat ~/.config/ranger/rifle.conf
ext org, has emacs,    terminal,  flag tf = emacs -nw "$@"
```

Hitting `r` in ranger

```
0 | emacs -nw "$@"
:open_with 0
```

This opens a new xterm, starting a new emacs editing the file in question.  You can simply press the `Return` key while on the file in question with this setup; using `r` would show all available options.

If you are living in the terminal and don't want to start another graphical terminal, I suggest using something like tmux - you can use tmux commands to open files, in this case like so

```
ext org, has emacs,    terminal,  flag f = tmux splitw -h emacs -nw "$@"
```

splitting the current pane (with ranger running), launching a new pane to the right of the current one and starting emacs there.  The pane will be closed when you quit emacs.  I'd probably start an emacsserver and use `emacsclient -nw` in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I tried what Tom had said but I found that there were too many steps to open my org file. I wanted to be able to just  press enter on an orgfile within ranger and have it open emacs -nw file.org, within the tmux pane running ranger.

The following solved my dilemma:

```
!mime ^text, label editor, ext org = emacs -nw -- "$@"
```